Error: UPGRADE FAILED: Kubernetes cluster unreachable: the server has asked for the client to provide credentials
I'm new to k8s, and I get this weird situation.
When running gitlab pipelines, sometimes (nearly half of the times) it fails with the aforementioned error.

Error: UPGRADE FAILED: Kubernetes cluster unreachable: the server has asked for the client to provide credentials

Other times it works.
I've seen another question about this error, but the account does not seem to be the issue, because it runs successfully after a fail without any changes implemented. Can someone point me what could be the reason of the issue?
Thanks in advance!
tried running pipeline in gitlab with k8s
was expecting success, got failure
